Can `Seq.truncate` after `Seq.distinct` in F# be beneficial in terms of performance
In the solution of the Pangram exercise:
let totalAlphabetCount = 1 + int ('Z' - 'A')

let isPangram (input: string): bool =
    input
    |> Seq.filter System.Char.IsAsciiLetter
    |> Seq.map System.Char.ToUpper
    |> Seq.distinct
    |> Seq.truncate totalAlphabetCount
    |> Seq.length = totalAlphabetCount

Does Seq.truncate totalAlphabetCount improve performance in huge input?
For example, we have a 1Gb string with all ASCII letters in the first hundred characters.

Some off the cuff observations: If you have to work with 1Gb strings, then your perf enhancements should start there. Do not use such large strings (remember, in .NET strings are immutable, so after each change they'll be copied). Instead use arrays. In your case, byte arrays would suffice. Do distinct first (or use distinctBy). Further,  map + filter = choose. Why do you truncate above the max length (you just did filter & distinct)?

And, if you need perf, in general, don't use Seq (it's the same as a .NET IEnumerable). Use lists or arrays, and to squeeze out most perf, use mutables, refs and spans.

In fact, without answering your question, your code doesn't seem to work properly. Try for example the non-pangram “The quick rown fox jumps over the lazy dog” where the letter b for brown is missing. Your implementation returns “true” when it's not true.

let phrase = "The quick rown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
printf $"%A{isPangram phrase}"
// false

Ah, my bad. I used a wrong alphabet.

The answer is yes. I ran an empirical test on my computer, with the following results:

With truncate: 0.0154 milliseconds
Without truncate 1150.0 milliseconds

This is a difference of several orders of magnitude!
The reason for this is that Seq.distinct is a lazy function.
With the call to Seq.truncate in place, Seq.distinct will stop iterating once it finds 26 distinct characters, which happens in the first 100 characters of the input. Without the call to Seq.truncate, Seq.distinct must continue looking for distinct characters through the entire string, even though we know that it's not possible that others exist.
For clarity, here's the implementation of Seq.distinct to show its lazy behavior:
    let distinct source =
        checkNonNull "source" source

        seq {
            let hashSet = HashSet<'T>(HashIdentity.Structural<'T>)

            for v in source do
                if hashSet.Add v then
                    yield v
        }

Test code:
let rng = Random(0)

let randomChar _ =
    rng.Next(32, 128)
        |> char

let randomString len =
    Array.init len randomChar
        |> String

let str =
    randomString 1_000_000_00

let test () =
    isPangram str |> ignore

test ()   // warmup

Seq.init 10 (fun _ ->
    let stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
    test ()
    stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds)
    |> Seq.average
    |> printfn "%A"


Yes, it improves the performance.
Adding this step - Seq.truncate totalAlphabetCount avoids unnecessary calculations once we reach the goal.
